# How to read a particular text of a php file in codeigniter using php tokenizer

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to read a commented text from a php file using php tokenizer in codeigniter.

**PHP File**

```
<?php
   //example of php tokenizer
   //@module   core
   //@author   VR
?>
```

How can i get the module or author name in my variable.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using [token_get_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) and the [T_COMMENT](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) constant, than you just need to parse out the `module` and `author`.

So given the example file contents you want to parse, you can do it like:

```
<?php
$source = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);

$result = [];
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
   if ($token[0] === T_COMMENT) {
        $token[1] = trim($token[1], '/ ');

        if (in_array(substr($token[1], 0, 7), ['@module', '@author'])) {
            $result[substr($token[1], 1, 6)] = trim(substr($token[1], 7));
        }
   }
}

print_r($result);

/*
Array
(
    [module] => core
    [author] => VR
)
*/
```